# java type for oracle string

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, oracle11g

I have a stored procedure and I can execute it on plsql. Now I want to call it from my eclipse. don't worry about the connection, it is correct.

In the plsql I see two variables for this stored procedure. the top one is the result which is string , the below one is my variable which is string too.

I have tried:

```
callablestatement = {call mystroedprocedure (?,?)}
callablestatement.registeroutparameter(1, OracleTypes.varchar);
callablestatement.setString(2, "5555");
```

But I got this exception:

```
java.sql.sqlexception: ora-06550: line 1, column 7:
pls_00306: wrong number of types of arguments in call to 'mystroedprocedure'
ORA-06550: line 1, colmuns 7:
PL/SQL: statemnent ignored.
```

I can't see the body of the stored procedure because I don't have privilege.

I am using ojdbc6.jar

Comment: Are you sure mystroedprocedure() has two parameters?

Comment: yes of corse, 100% i am sure

Comment: typo `callablestatement.registeroutparameer`? parameter

Comment: yes they all typo, forgive me, i dont have the IDE in this computer

Comment: Can you try `Types.VARCHAR` instead of `OracleTypes.VARCHAR`. Example [link](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/using-ref-cursors-to-return-recordsets.php)

Comment: @learningloop i tried , still the same

Comment: One more thing, `callablestatement` assignment should be like `callablestatement = conn.prepareCall("{? = CALL mystroedprocedure(?)}");`. Example [link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/F49540_01/DOC/java.815/a64686/04_call5.htm)

Comment: @learningloop: That is a function. Since OP is sure the procedure has two parameters, the correct syntax should be `callablestatement = conn.prepareCall("{call mystroedprocedure(?, ?)}");`